# how to update datetime value from i.e 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value to null

Tags: mysql

Dear sir have a table in which I take a column updatetime with datetime datatype and also it is null by default. Now I want to replace some values  from 0000-00-00 00:00:0 to null when I try to execute update query in phpmyadmin it give me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwhSM.jpg).Please help me how I update this column.`

```
UPDATE tbl_table_time
set update_datetime = NULL
WHERE update_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

```
ID  Updatetime (Datatype datetime)
1   0000-00-00 00:00:00

2   2020-12-03 16:19:07

3   0000-00-00 00:00:00

4   2020-12-03 16:19:07

5   0000-00-00 00:00:00

6   0000-00-00 00:00:00

7   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: Please post the ERROR message as text, not linked picture

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `SET update_datetime = NULL` but the `WHERE update_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` of your query. The error indicates, that `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid **Datetime**, which is correct, as the lowest possible **Datetime** is `1000-01-01 00:00:00`. Because of this MySQL does not want to compare the **Datetime** values. To overcome this, it's easiest, to convert the **Datetime** to an actual **string** for the comparison. Here is an example query:

```
UPDATE tbl_table_time SET update_datetime = NULL WHERE CAST(update_datetime AS CHAR(20)) = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Keep in mind that this is not very efficient and could take a while on large databases. And as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is a faulty state, it should be avoided and you should check, how it ended up in the database anyway. MySQL is converting invalid **Datetimes** into this zero-state automatically, but this can also be disabled. For more details see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html